# How to fix 'Expressions are not allowed at the top level' error in Swift when trying to call a function to start the app?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, expression

dear community,

I faced an issue writing my app in Swift. I am writing it in Xcode. I want to make an app that will work on Mac without further installation of frameworks. I wrote the code but faced the issue with the recurring (Expressions are not allowed at the top level error). The thing is that I have come to a dead end. For instance, I have 5 functions that do some actions. But I need to call the first one to start. But it is not allowed to make calls on top, so I need to encapsulate the call into another function. But the problem is, who will call that another function? So I can't start loading the app without calling the functions. But I can't call since the call cannot be on the top level. So how am I supposed even to start the execution of my app?

```
import Foundation

struct Recipient: Codable {
    let name: String
}

struct Period: Codable {
    let startDate: String
    let endDate: String
    let recipient: Recipient
}

struct Rotation: Codable {
    let periods: [Period]
}

struct Schedule: Codable {
    let finalTimeline: Rotation
}

class DataProcessor {
    let apiKey = ""
    let scheduleID = ""
    let date = "2023-05-25" // Change this to the desired date
    
    func fetchDataAndProcess() {
        let urlString = ""
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Invalid API endpoint URL.")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            defer {
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data received.")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let schedule = try JSONDecoder().decode(Schedule.self, from: data)
                let rotations = schedule.finalTimeline.periods
                
                // Process the rotations and perform calculations
                
                var resultArray: [[String: String]] = []
                
                for period in rotations {
                    let startDate = formatDate(period.startDate)
                    let endDate = formatDate(period.endDate)
                    let days = calculateDays(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
                    let pay = calculatePay(days: days)
                    let name = period.recipient.name
                    
                    let result: [String: String] = [
                        "Start Date": startDate,
                        "Days": days,
                        "Pay": "\(pay) EUR",
                        "End Date": endDate,
                        "Name": name
                    ]
                    
                    resultArray.append(result)
                }
                
                // Save the results to a file
                
                let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "result.csv")
                
                saveResultArray(resultArray, to: fileURL) { success, url in
                    if success {
                        print("Results saved to: \(url)")
                    } else {
                        print("Failed to save results.")
                    }
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                return
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
    }
    
    // Function to format date as dd.mm.yy
    func formatDate(_ dateString: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yy"
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            return formatter.string(from: date)
        }
        
        return ""
    }
    
    // Function to calculate number of days between two dates
    func calculateDays(startDate: String, endDate: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yy"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        
        if let startDate = formatter.date(from: startDate),
           let endDate = formatter.date(from: endDate) {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
            
            if let days = components.day {
                return String(days)
            }
        }
        
        return ""
    }
    
    // Function to calculate pay based on the number of days
    func calculatePay(days: String) -> Int {
        if let days = Int(days) {
            return days * 30
        }
        
        return 0
    }
    
    // Function to save result array to a CSV file
    func saveResultArray(_ resultArray: [[String: String]], to fileURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool, URL) -> Void) {
        var csvText = "Start Date,Days,Pay,End Date,Name\n"
        
        for result in resultArray {
            let startDate = result["Start Date"] ?? ""
            let days = result["Days"] ?? ""
            let pay = result["Pay"] ?? ""
            let endDate = result["End Date"] ?? ""
            let name = result["Name"] ?? ""
            
            let newLine = "\(startDate),\(days),\(pay),\(endDate),\(name)\n"
            csvText.append(newLine)
        }
        
        do {
            try csvText.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            completion(true, fileURL)
        } catch {
            completion(false, fileURL)
        }
    }
}

let dataProcessor = DataProcessor()
dataProcessor.fetchDataAndProcess()
```

I tried encapsulating the function into another function, creating a few files to link them together, and encapsulating the call into another function and calling it later. However, the call is still considered the expression on top. So there is no way to start the app.

Comment: Did you use one of the supplied project templates for a Mac OS app in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I used the template that they supply in Xcode. I can try creating a new app without the template.

Comment: If this is supposed to be a command line interface you need a main entry point, either by naming the file main.swift or with the `@main` attribute. And please stop using a semaphore to force asynchronous code to become synchronous. Learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works which is pretty easy with Swift Concurrency.

Comment: No you should use the template but that also means you have a main class where you can move the faulting code lines to.

Comment: I created the file main.swift. But it doesn't fixes the issue with the expression on top.

Comment: what kind of application template did you select? An `App`,  `Document App`, or `Command Line Tool` ...